# How to define a \school that set the \@school variable?

Tags: macros, titles

I would like to customize the `\maketitle` by adding two new fields: `\department` and `\school`.

I want to add them in a custom-defined `\def\@maketitle{%`. I naively tried this:

```
\providecommand{\school}[1]{\newcommand{\@school}[1]{\school}}
```

Comment: Try `\makeatletter\providecommand{\school}[1]{\newcommand{\@school}[1]{#1))\makeatother`. You can omit `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` if the definition is part of a file that will be loaded with `\usepackage`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LaTeX defines `\author` as

```
\DeclareRobustCommand*\author[1]{\gdef\@author{#1}}
```

You can define `\school` and `\department` in the same way:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand*\School[1]{\gdef\@School{#1}}
\DeclareRobustCommand*\Department[1]{\gdef\@Department{#1}}
```

`@` may not occur in the name of a macro on user level, so you have either to enclose the definitions between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` (and put the commands into your preamble) or to put them into a file `mydefs.sty` and load this file in the preamble with `\usepackage{mydefs}`.

Probably the easiest way to create a new `\maketitle` command is to leave the old one as it is and use it in your definition.

```
\DeclareRobustCommand*\Author[1]{\gdef\@Author{#1}}
\newcommand\Maketitle{%
   \author{\@Author\\\@School, \@Department}%
   \maketitle
}
```

Note that we need a new `\author` command, as we need the original command to combine school and department with the author.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand*\School[1]{\gdef\@School{#1}}
\DeclareRobustCommand*\Department[1]{\gdef\@Department{#1}}
\DeclareRobustCommand*\Author[1]{\gdef\@Author{#1}}
\newcommand\Maketitle{%
  \author{\@Author\\\@School, \@Department}%
  \maketitle
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\title{My Article}
\Author{It's me}
\School{my school}
\Department{my department}
\Maketitle
\end{document}
```